# What does this bash script involving "read" do?

Tags: bash, herestring

I found this in one of the bash scripts for capturing metrics running on CentOS.

```
read  -rd '' count <<< "$count"
```

I know **read** reads the content of file descriptor into buffer, but I cannot find the documentation for the command line switches -r, -d.

Additionally, What does triple left arrow <<< do?

Comment: Which `man` page did _not_ contain the description for those flags?

Comment: The `<<<` is a bashism called the *Herestring* and it redirects the variable `$count` as if it were a file on `stdin` allowing it to be read by `read` - which in this case reads ignoring escapes (`-r`) until the delimiter (`-d ' '`) (space) is found. Type `man bash` then `3813g`  return (and look for `read`) That will get you close to the correct line. Or you can just type `/-ers` return and it will take you there.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. I was looking for -r and -d in `man read`.

Comment: Glad to help. `man bash` is a bit frightening the first couple of times to peer inside. But after a while you figure out it is laid out in handful of sections that you can usually jump to and find what you need. A 30 min. read of the entire `EXPANSION` section will save you 100-fold that amount of time later in your use of bash `:)` (especially the `"Parameter Expansion"` sub-section)

Comment: Depending on your platform, `man read` might bring up a man page from [section 2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/intro) of the manual; on my Mac, it gets redirected to [man builtins](https://linux.die.net/man/1/builtins) which appears to be the behavior at least on some Linux platforms now too.

Comment: I upvoted to counter attack the phantom downvoter. This is a perfectly good question and reading all these comments is super informative and entertaining. Which one would assume is the whole point of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are Bash features which you will find amply documented in the [Bash manual.](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html)

`<<<` is ["here string"](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) format; it's sort of like a here document:

```
cat <<____HERE
    Hello, World!
____HERE
```

... except the token after the separator is the actual string to pass in as standard input to the command.

The `-r` option to [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) disables some legacy behavior with backslashes from the original Bourne shell.

`-d` sets the record delimiter. An empty string says to stop reading when you get a NUL character.

Comment: Does this mean the above code is equivalent to `echo $count | read -rd count`?

Comment: Not exactly, because `read` in a subprocess (as in, at the end of a pipeline) generally doesn't work; and you forgot the argument to the option `-d`, which requires one; and also you failed to quote `echo "$count"`. But that's the idea, yes.

Comment: Also, some versions of `echo` can mangle or misinterpret some strings. Re the original question: I’m curious what this actually accomplishes (other than adding a newline to the string).